# Bijection between sets homotopy classes and homotopy

Tags: homotopy-theory

I want to see intuition , how to work with homotopy classes of spaces. Here is the problem: given two topological spaces X and Y, also we have that for every top. space Z
there is bijection between [Z,X] and [Z,Y],and i need to prove that X is homotopic to X.
I tried to use bijection between [X,X] and [X,Y] and see what it can give me, but i only understood that, if [X,X] has one element, then X contractible,so [X,Y] has one element,thus Y is contractible too,so X is homotopic to Y in this case.

Comment: If the bijection is natural this is a straightforward application of the Yoneda lemma. Is it not necessarily required to be natural?

Comment: Bijection is natural,but I want to prove it without Yoneda lemma. Is it possible?

Comment: You'll basically end up reproving the Yoneda lemma. Just go through the proof and see what it says in this case.

Comment: This is not an answer, just some information to perhaps help your intuition: since (letting $Z=Y$) there is a bijection $[Y,X] \leftrightarrow [Y,Y]$, the identity map for $Y$ corresponds to a particular map $Y \to X$; since it corresponds to the identity map, you might be willing to believe that it is somehow special. Similarly, the identity map for $X$ corresponds to a special map $X \to Y$. Perhaps those maps should be homotopy inverses to each other...